# Using dynamic programming to find minimum cost of a pipeline

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

I am learning dynamic programming and I have this is problem that i can't understand.

We have a a pipeline that is connected by depos (pumps). The pipeline is linear and we have assigned the depos a value. For example 4----5----1----2 (shows a pipeline, with numbers representing pumps/depos), the total value of pipeline is computed as 4*5 +4*1 + 4*2 + 5*1 + 5*2 + 1*2 = 49.

We are now given with a problem to cut the water supply at such a point that we are left with the minimum value of pipeline for example cutting between 5 and 1 gives us 22 (4---5--/--1---2 gives as 4*5  +  1*2  =  22.)
while cutting it at 4 and 5 gives 17 ( 4--/--5--1---2 gives 5*1 + 5*2  +  1*2 = 17). We are allowed a limited number of cuts. and we are to device a dynamic algorithm that gives us the least pipeline cost.

Comment: Calculate sum of numbers and sum of their squares for every subpipeline.

Comment: The trick is to see how the problem can be subdivided.  Suppose there are n depos and you are allowed up to k cuts.  In any solution (set of up to k cuts) with >= 1 cuts, one cut is the *rightmost* cut.  Let's consider putting this rightmost cut between depos i and i+1: the minimum value that we could get from doing this must be the same as the value of the entire pipeline starting from depo i+1 and extending right to the end, plus the *minimum* value we could get by putting at most k-1 cuts into the first i depos.  Notice how that second part is a smaller version of the original problem :)

Comment: The fact that you can subdivide the problem into a an easy-to-solve part (the pipeline segment on the right of the rightmost cut) and a smaller version of the original problem shows right away that the problem can be solved recursively.  What makes this recursion amenable to DP is that the solution to a particular subproblem might be needed many times -- so it's better to compute each subproblem's solution once and store it.

Comment: @j_random_hacker And more importantly, that the number of different subproblems to solve is within reasonable limits

Comment: @NiklasB.: Do you mean the space cost of DP (vs. plain recursion)?  Sure that's important, but I wouldn't say it's more important than the basic required property of optimal substructure!

Comment: @j_random_hacker I mean that you can find optimal substructure everywhere, but it doesn't always lead to a polynomial number of states :) It's very important (and often hard) to find the "right" structure which yields an efficient algorithm. I'm sure you know that, just wanted to point it out to OP. I shouldn't have pinged you :P

Comment: @NiklasB.: Agree with you about it being hard to find the "right" structure, but I don't yet get what you mean about optimal substructure being everywhere...  (Could be insufficient coffee :) Could you give an example?  Also DP can still be useful on exponential-sized state sets (e.g. the DP for TSP).

Comment: @j_random_hacker Yeah I mean you can always define somelike like subsets as your state, even if it is sufficient to work with contiguous ranges or something. There was not really anything deep about my comment ;) And of course DP on subsets has its uses for hard problems

Comment: @j_random_hacker I still don't get what i can take as a subproblem. I tried using a 2D array to store the products of the deops. then calculated the cost for all the sub pipelines for k=1. I then choose the k with the minimum cost and then calculate the costs for remaining sub pipelines for k=2 and so on. This gives me the right answer but i still don't get if this is a dynamic programming approach or not?

Comment: @Uan: I can't tell from that description whether what you're doing is DP -- it might be, but you might also be computing "too much".  I find it easiest to approach a DP problem by first writing a recursive solution, then memoizing it.  This means writing a recursive function that solves any arbitrary subproblem; here it will take 2 parameters, n (meaning to use the first n depos in the given (global) list of depos) and k (the maximum number of cuts).  That will usually be fast enough, but if not, you can sometimes get a constant-factor speedup by building the DP table bottom-up.